# How to avoid javascript `window.open` triggering popup window alert

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to build an off-site notification function in jQuery. The script first checks if the link is an external link and then checks against a db table entries for exceptions. If the link is external and not on the list of exceptions, send the visitor to a notification page. If it is an external link that's on the exception list, then open the link in a new window without the notification page.

I'm using a jQuery `$.post` call to send the link info out to a php script that retrieves the exceptions and returns a yes or no for if it needs to go to the notification screen. Here's the code:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var url =$(this).attr('href');

    if(url !== '#'){ 
        // ignore links that don't 'go' anywhere 

        if($(this).hasClass('alerted')){
            // .alerted is used on the notification page to show the user's already been notified & prevents an infinite loop of notifications.
            window.open(url);
            return false;

        }else if(url.substr(0,4) !='http'){
            // check that the url isn't an internal link ('/page.php' for example)
            return true;
        }

        // ajax script to check url is external and is there an exception. Returns as json object:
        // link: link
        // notify: true/false
        $.post("/scripts/form_process.php", { action : 'offsite', link: url}, function(data){
            if(data.notify == true){
                // if visitors should be notified, redirect to the following link:
                window.location= '/leaving-site?link='+encodeURIComponent(data.link);
                return false;
            }else{
                // if the link is in the exception list, don't notify but do open the link in a new window:
                window.open(data.link);
            }

        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

This is working fine except that so long as the `window.open(url)` command is inside the `$.post` success function, the browser is treating it like a popup instead of as a natural link. This seems to be a problem when using `window.open` inside the `ajax` call as far as I can tell. When I use it here:

```
        if($(this).hasClass('alerted')){
            // .alerted is used on the notification page to show the user's already been notified & prevents an infinite loop of notifications.
            window.open(url);
            return false;
        }
```

I don't get the pop up blocker.

I can't hard code the exceptions list and I have to check every link - I can't assume a class will be added to the links that need to be notified for example.

How can I open the external link in a new tab and avoid the popup blocker in this code?

Comment: You're right, as long as it falls outside of that click's "thread", it will be treated like an unsolicited popup. Are we talking a lot of links here? Is it plausible you could, on page load, go grab the external links and validate them in the background while the user's viewing the current content?

Comment: popup blockers allow things based on whether a user's direct/actual click triggered the code calling window.open. an ajax response handler is obviously not one of those things. it's not triggered by a click, but by some network activity. doesn't matter that this network activity was caused by a click - there's no direct link between the click on the link and the triggering of the success handler. therefore it gets blocked.

Comment: @Brad Cristie - this site is client editable so every link on the site has to be checked, so yes potentially a lot of links. The answer below seems to solve it though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The classic way to solve this is as follows:
Create the new window before the AJAX call:

```
var newWindow = window.open('', '_blank');
```

And in the success - you assign the URL to the new window like so:

```
newWindow.location.href = 'http://example.com';
```

Full example with your code:

```
$('a').click(function(){

    var url =$(this).attr('href');

    if(url !== '#'){ 
        // ignore links that don't 'go' anywhere 

        if($(this).hasClass('alerted')){
            // .alerted is used on the notification page to show the user's already been notified & prevents an infinite loop of notifications.
            window.location = url;
            return false;

        }else if(url.substr(0,4) !='http'){
            // check that the url isn't an internal link ('/page.php' for example)
            return true;
        }

        // ajax script to check url is external and is there an exception. Returns as json object:
        // link: link
        // notify: true/false
         var newWindow = window.open('', '_blank');
        $.post("/scripts/form_process.php", { action : 'offsite', link: url}, function(data){
            if(data.notify == true){
                // if visitors should be notified, redirect to the following link:
                newWindow.location.href= '/leaving-site?link='+encodeURIComponent(data.link);
                return false;
            }else{
                // if the link is in the exception list, don't notify but do open the link in a new window:
                newWindow.location.href(data.link);
            }

        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: That works with a slight adjustment: move the newWindow line to just above the `$.post` so that it doesn't open a new blank window for an internal link or one that's already had the notification. Have edited so this isn't a problem

Comment: Ah right - thanks for the edit! Glad I was able to help, @TH1981